# Using Minor Upgrade to deliver a few new files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am doing a PoC that involves creating an MSI that has version 1.0.0.0; installing that version to a test machine.

Next, I create another MSI (same name, same product code, different package code, same upgrade code). I merely added a single new .txt file to the sources of the original (v1.0.0.0) MSI. I create the new MSI file using WiX and give it version 1.1.0.0.

All good so far.

Here's a breakdown of the codes so far (from Orca.exe):

```
ProductCode for msi-v1.0.0.0: {CBCF9206-1539-47B8-9A46-A18C2E40D7A1}
ProductCode for msi-v1.1.0.0: {CBCF9206-1539-47B8-9A46-A18C2E40D7A1}

PackageCode for msi-v1.0.0.0: {AB2B02E4-213E-48C1-9394-E30A75BAF2BE}
PackageCode for msi-v1.1.0.0: {C68D3A88-583A-41BF-A971-CB5E083B8547}

UpgradeCode for msi-v1.0.0.0: {06726F10-FF0B-4534-A008-032A70CACDBB}
UpgradeCode for msi-v1.1.0.0: {06726F10-FF0B-4534-A008-032A70CACDBB}

ProductVersion for msi-v1.0.0.0: 1.0.0.0
ProductVersion for msi-v1.1.0.0: 1.1.0.0
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the deployment of that new single .txt file via this Minor Upgrade. I know that there is a smaller type update called Small Update, but that is not where this PoC is headed. We will need to change the version number as a part of our end game.

I have this in the Wix script that is used to gen both the MSIs (I really don't think this has anything to do with my issue - just including it because it has the word 'Upgrade' in it):

```
<MajorUpgrade 
    DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." 
    AllowDowngrades="no" 
    AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" 
    />
```

What I am seeing is that when I run:

```
msiexec.exe /i FileName.msi REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL
```

I do not get the new single .txt file delivered. I do see that the product version (in appwiz.cpl) changes from 1.0.0.0 to 1.1.0.0, and the cached local MSI file (under C:\Windows\Installer dir) is indeed now version 1.1.0.0 (verified by Orca.exe).

I am puzzled as to why the new single .txt file is not being deployed.

I guess my primary question is: Why won't this Minor Upgrade (i.e. same product code, diff package code, diff product version) deliver the new file?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Please also note that there are no errors in the setup log either. The upgrade appears to work - except for not delivering the new .txt file.

Comment: How did you add the file, to an existing or new component and existing or new feature or subfeature?

Comment: Can you post the entire log file somewhere?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, I think you may have nailed it. The way we auto-gen the .wxs recreates the <Component/Id/GUID> piece. I'm betting that the Component Id and GUID change is what is throwing it off. Is that a true statement? If true, it's going to be fun to keep those attributes constant. I am unable to post the log file as it has sensitive information in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read:

[What happens if the component rules are broken?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and

[Dealing with very large number of files](http://blog.iswix.com/2007/06/dealing-with-very-large-number-of-files.html)

I'm not a huge opponent of this type of automation.  Especially if you are trying to do minor upgrades and patches.   Far too often I find people who learn a little bit about installers, don't really want to do it and find it more interesting and "automated" to automate the automation.  Don't do it! :)  Instead I focus on creating processes that make installer development and maintenance as easy as possible.  (See [IsWiX on CodePlex](http://iswix.codeplex.com/))    Only the experienced developer knows his code and can make the right choices on how to deploy his resources.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I am a bit more confused now - not a far trip these days...from the first link, [What happens...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I appear to not be breaking the rule: "An author adds resources to a component without the changing the component code." I added a resource (file) and changed the component Id and GUID. I am assuming that the Component Id is strictly for WiX's internal use and the GUID is the important part to the Installer, yes?

Comment: Let me go educate myself a bit more. I am afraid I am wasting your time here trying to bring me up to speed.

Comment: Keeping the component GUID constant across builds appears to do what I need done (i.e. add the solitary new .txt file to the installation already present).

Comment: Up votes and accepted answers are always appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you broke the component rules you'll see something in the log about it. There'll be SELMGR entries and something about removing components being unsupported. That might happen if you didn't add the file correctly. If you do the minor update install with MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES set to 1 on the command line it will fail the install if you broke the rules.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I forgot about that property.  That's a good one to know.